# Android layouts: how to put logo over border of two elements?

Tags: android, android-layout

I make my Android app. Client’s requirement is to put logo to the bottom toolbar. The problem is that logo should be placed half over the bottom toolbar and half over the content. The problem is that I can not to negative margins, so I cannot shift logo image neither down from content, nor up over the toolbar. It should look so:

[image]

I made two toolbars – transparent and filled. But the problem is that I cannot stretch bottom of the content to the top of the filled toolbar because it is inside the transparent toolbar. Here is the picture and code.

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBrandColor"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sponge_bob" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame_to_inflate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf ="@+id/toolbarTop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/toolbarBottomTransparent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarBottomTransparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content_frame_to_inflate"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarBottomFilled"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorBrandColor"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sponge_bob_logo"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I do proper layout?

Comment: what happens if you used relativelayout instead of contraint?

Comment: How can I center image on the toolbar top in ralative layout?

Comment: whats the purpose of the toolbar at the bottom?

Comment: you can just put a layout there and set the background blue. then put image under the layout. that should overlay it

Comment: Later there will be controls in toolbar (like search). The problem is that content bottom is the top of image instead of being the top of the toolbar. You can see the difference comparing two screenshots. It's not a problem if I don't have the image. Adding one more layout or toolbar doesn't let me to constraint bottom of the content properly

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cdcdcd"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame_to_inflate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf ="@+id/toolbarTop"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#cdcdcd"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



    </RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

***UPDATED LAYOUT***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#4984ad"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame_to_inflate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarTop"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#4984ad"
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



    </RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/SpongeBob_SquarePants_logo"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: But this '     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" ' links the image to the bottom of the toolbar instead of placing the center of the image at the top of toolbar

Comment: im not adding a toolbar at the bottom. you dont have to either. the bottom=true pins that relative layout to the bottom. look at the image. the blackbox is your image. if i had the images i could develop it for ya...but i dont. itll work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the problem is that in your code logo image Y position is hardcoded. So I always should change its position. I hoped to find the way to setup relative vertical position for the image.

Comment: in what cases would the logo not be in the middle at the bottom?

Comment: It should be there all the time. This layout as you can see is parent layout for all activities. Parent activity class inflates some content there. And, of course, bottom toolbar might change its height. So I need some solution that doesn't use hardcoded image position

Comment: fyi, im not hard coding an image position..... you dont have to do margin-bottom. i did that to illustrate a black box. your image will be a png...you will still have to raise it, maybe

Comment: But how can I define its position in other way to put its y-center at the toolbar top?

Comment: Sorry, probably I miss something but this is the issue I try to understand

Comment: As you can see on screenshots I posted, logo y-center should be placed at the top of toolbar. So top half of the logo is over the content and bottom half – over the toolbar.

Comment: that code has a toolbar for the top....and a layout thats located at the bottom. you can put small buttons in there if you wanted too...doesnt matter. then, i added an imageview OUTSIDE of that layout and also put it at the bottom in the middle.... that is how you allot the image to float on top

Comment: can you post the images .... idk... maybe you cant picture it bc im not using images...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151087/discussion-between-yura-and-droidev).